How can i do auto instantiation on top block in Verilog mode?
In a Verilog file, here is my submodule and top module. I am trying to do auto instantiations in a module where some ports are already instantiated, a few ports are declared and the rest of the things will be done with the help of emacs verilog-mode.
     module submodule (
         input [31:0] in_t_data,
         input in_t_valid,
         output in_t_ready
         output [31:0] out_t_data,
         output out_t_valid,
         input out_t_ready,
         input [3:0] in_t_id,
         output [1:0] out_t_resp,
         input clk,
         input rstn
     );
     //logic written here
     endmodule

     module top (
         input clk,
         input rstn
         /*AUTOINPUT*/
         /*AUTOOUTPUT*/
     );
     /*AUTOWIRE*/
     /*
     submodule AUTO_TEMPLATE (
         .in_t_\(.*\) (bus_\1\2),
         .out_t_(.*\) (ctrl_\1\2),
         );
     */
     submodule u_submodule (
         /*AUTOINST*/
         // Outputs
         .out_t_valid  (ctrl_valid),
         // Inputs
         .out_t_ready  (ctrl_ready)
     );
     endmodule

but after running verilog batch mode command on top.v(the top module) this code i am not getting desired output :-
     module top
          input clk,
          input rstn,
     /*AUTOOUTPUT*/
     // Beginning of automatic outputs
     output          bus_ready,
     output          ctrl_data,
     output          ctrl_resp,
     output          ctrl_valid,
     // End of automatics
     /*AUTOINPUT*/
     //Beginning of automatic inputs
     input           bus_data,
     input           bus_id,
     input           bus_valid,
     input           ctrl_ready
     // End of automatics
     /*AUTOARG*/)
     
     /*AUTOWIRE*/
     /*
     submodule AUTO_TEMPLATE (
               .in_t_\(.*\)  (bus_\1\2),
               .out_t_\(.*\) (ctrl_\1\2),);*/
     submodule u_submodule (
               /*AUTOINST*/
               // Outputs
               .in_t_ready     (bus_ready),
               .out_t_data     (ctrl_data),
               .out_t_valid    (ctrl_valid),
               .out_t_resp     (ctrl_resp),
               // Inputs
               .out_t_ready     (ctrl_ready),
               .in_t_data       (bus_data),
               .in_t_valid      (bus_valid),
               .in_t_id         (bus_id),
               .clk             (clk),
               .rstn            (rstn)
     );
     
     endmodule

but the actual width I am not getting in top module and auto wire is also not generating. What will be the solution for these?
